# Accessing Singleton Instance Variable in Class Methods Throws Warning?

Tags: objective-c

I've using the [Objective-C singleton from here at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like).

The singleton in the class method accesses it's instance variable, which works, but throws a complie warning. How should I be doing this? Is there a way to do this without accessing the `sharedInstance:` in each class method?

for example here is my class method:

```
+ (NSString *)myClassMethods {
    [instanceDateFormatter setFormat:@"MM"];
    return [instanceDateFormatter stringWithDate:somedate];
}
```

line 2 will have the complie warning.

Thanks,
Ross

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using the `sharedInstance:` call in each class method.  I guess if you *really* want to, you could work around it with global variables, but the *right* solution is as you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Since `instanceDataFormatter` is an instance variable, you have to access it via a class instance -- so you'll need to go through your `sharedInstance` method to get it. Or, you could access it via the static singleton variable, bypassing the call to `sharedInstance` (however, that could break if the static variable hasn't been initialized yet).